# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager and Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wso2, wso2-iot

I'm trying to install a WSO2 EMM server on Amazon EC2 Instance, but have a problem with it. EC2 instance have 2 IP addresses - one of them is internal Amazon address like 172.32.x.x, another is external real IP.

If I try to setup carbon.xml file with real IP (or domain), I have a problem with thrift server, which can't open port 10500 at a real IP. If I use internal IP running of server is fine, but in application I can't reach identity server (because it's a gray IP, of course).

I tried some tricks with using /etc/hosts file, for example, setup 0.0.0.0 as *my domain*. In this case server is running without errors, and a can see that port 10500 is open using netstat, but web application is not redirect to identity server.

May be there are any solutions of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have to update EMM server to version 1.1.0 and all is working now.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

In the carbon.xml, change the HostName and MgtHostName to the real IP and start the server.
For example if the real IP is 172.32.x.x then HostName and MgtHostName in the carbon.xml should change to:

```
<HostName>172.32.x.x</HostName>
<MgtHostName>172.32.x.x</MgtHostName>
```